# How is it possible for the inverse function of a linear-continuous-bijective function to be not continuous?

Tags: vector-spaces

If $E$ and $F$ are two normed vector spaces, $f:E\rightarrow F$ is a linear-continuous-bijective function. Then naturally I would think that $f^{-1}$ is also linear-continuous-bijective. But the textbook says that $f^{-1}$ can be non-continuous. I can't figure out why.

Can anyone raise a simple example?

Comment: Same strategy as in the previous: write down a bounded invertible operator whose inverse isn't bounded.

Comment: My bad. Asking without thinking. So the critical problem I have here is my intuition is limited within the finite dimensional spaces, while things are much different in the infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: The construction is very similar to the construction I used in your other question. Just think about it for a bit. I would recommend using the same normed spaces again or perhaps a slight modification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the space
$$c_{00}:=\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mid \exists N\in\mathbb{N}:a_n=0\enspace\forall n\geq N\}$$
of sequences with finite support over a field $\mathbb{F}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ and let
$$ ||(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}||_\infty:=\sup\left\{|a_n| \mathrel{\big|} n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}$$
be the norm. Set $E:=F:=c_{00}$. A sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is defined to be a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{F}$.

---

Now consider the operator
$$f:c_{00}\to c_{00}, \qquad f((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}):=\left(\tfrac{1}{n}a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
which is obviously linear, bounded and bijective with inverse $f^{-1}((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})= (na_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. The inverse is not bounded. To see this, view the sequence $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  of "unit vectors"
$$e_1:=(1,0,0,\ldots),\quad e_2:=(0,1,0,0,\ldots), \quad e_3:=(0,0,1,0,0,\ldots),\quad\ldots$$
in $c_{00}$. Obviously we have $||e_n||_\infty=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so $||f^{-1}(e_n)||_\infty=n=n||e_n||_\infty$. Thus
$$\frac{||f^{-1}(e_n)||_\infty}{||e_n||_\infty}=n\to \infty \qquad\text{ as } n\to\infty,$$
so $f^{-1}$ cannot be bounded.

Note that $c_{00}$ is not a Banach space and that this map therefore provides a counterexample to the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem), if one removes the assumption of completeness.