# Continuous linear operator with noncontinuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150253/how-is-it-possible-for-the-inverse-function-of-a-linear-continuous-bijective-fun) gave an example of a continuous $f: E \rightarrow F$ which is bijective but has noncontinuous inverse. In the example, neither $E$ nor $F$ was a Banach space, are there any examples where $E$ or $F$ is a Banach space (of course, none exist if both $E$ and $F$ are Banach, by an application of the open mapping theorem).

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291671/open-mapping-theorem-counterexample).

Answer (score 3):

Let $E=C([0,1],\Bbb R)$ (continuous maps frome $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$)  with $\|.\|_{\infty}$ and $\|.\|_1$ and identical mape : $f \mapsto f$ frome $(E,\|.\|_{\infty})$ to $(E,\|.\|_{1})$

Comment: But, are both Banach spaces?

Comment: i am editing with an other example. the question says $$E$ or $F$ Banach ...

Comment: It's well known that $(E, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is Banach and $(E, \|\cdot\|_1)$ is not.